# read_csv, non-printing ascii delimiters, and multi index

Tags: pandas, csv

I have some text data which uses the [ASCII data characters](https://www.asciitable.com/) `0x1e` "group separator" and `0x1d` "record separator" to store hierarchical data, as follows:

```
A 0x1e   B 0x1d C 0x1d D 0x1d E   0x1e F 0x1d G 0x1d H 0x1d I  [newline]
J 0x1e   K 0x1d L 0x1d M 0x1d N   0x1e P 0x1d Q 0x1d R 0x1d S  [newline]
...
```

The whitespace is of course fictional, and the actual file contents would be more like

```
$ hexdump -C file.ext | head -1
00000000  41 1e 42 1d 43 1d 44 1d  45 1e 46 1e 47 1d 48 1d    |A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.|
```

I would like `pandas` to load this data into a MultiIndex'd dataframe, like

```
       group0    group1                         group2
 idx   thing0    thing1 thing2 thing3 thing4    thing4 thing5 thing6 thing7
 0     A         B      C      D      E         F      G      H      I
 1     J         K      L      M      N         P      Q      R      S
```

Header names are arbitrary, and could come from `names=`.  The number of fields in each group is variable (but fixed in each table).  The data are variable-length strings.  Different tables have different-length groups, and I would prefer not to count them by squinting at each data file.

Is there an elegant way to do this import?

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', names=names)

#work-around to identify multi indices
indices = []
for iGroup, tmpGroup in enumerate(df.iloc[0,0].split('1e')):
    for iThing in range(len(tmpGroup.split('1d'))):
        indices.append(tuple(['group' + str(iGroup), 'thing' + str(iThing)]))

#decode and set the data
df = df.iloc[:,0].str.replace('1d','1e').str.split('1e', expand=True)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: bytes.fromhex(x).decode('ASCII'))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indices)
```

`df` results in

```
  group0 group1                      group2 group3       
  thing0 thing0 thing1 thing2 thing3 thing0 thing0 thing1
0      A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H
1      I      P      Q      R      S      T      U      V
```